# Not able to get data-bound data during the directive initialization when its wrapped in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been creating a modularized start page (In Angular).
I've created a module-directive that can handle simple data and displaying them as a list.

Originally, my plan was to create new directives that could handle other types of data and simply use the directive tag that was needed.
I changed my mind when I read about dynamically changing the directive templateUrl, which worked perfectly. I set the templateUrl with a function that read a value from the element and returned the desired template.

This is where the problems started. I added a moduleType to my objects and thought I could read the value in the same way as I did when the value was hardcoded on the element. No such luck.

Since I'm using ng-repeat to create a module for every object in the list I realized that the data-binding hadn't been run before the directive got initialized, so all I got was "module.Type" instead of the actual value. The modules work when the compile is done but I need the data before the data-bindings are made.

From what I've learned ng-repeat creates separate scopes for the items before it's compiled and the data-binding seems to happen after the compilation is done, but my directive needs to get the template/templateUrl before it starts compiling.

Relevant code example:

```
<div ng-repeat="module in tab.ActiveModules">
    <main-module id="{{module.ComponentId}}"
                title="{{module.Title}}"  
                data="module.Data"
                link="module.Link"
                link2="module.Link2"
                type="module.Type"> <!--Type is what should decide how the directive should behave-->
                <!--title, data, link/link2 are just module specific data, irrelevant for the question--> -->
    </main-module>
</div>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module("FrontPageControllerModule")
    .directive("mainModule", [function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                title: '@',
                data: '=',
                link: '=',
                link2: '=',
                type: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: function (element, attr) {
               switch (attr.type) {
                   case "link":
                       return "Templates/frontpagelink.html";
                   case "setting":
                       return "/Template/settings";
                   case "json":
                       this.controller = "JsonViewerController";
                       return "/Template/json-viewer";
                   default:
                       return "";
               }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code so we can see how you're approaching this.

Comment: What do you mean by "data binding" here? What are you expecting to happen, what is happening, and how do they differ?

Comment: Not sure what else to call it. What I am trying to refer to is when the angular expressions are translated to actual values. I want to set the templateUrl depending on what module.type it is.

Comment: I'm reading this as you trying to make the expressions in the directive view(s) wait until the directive view exists (i.e. has been provided) to render. It seems like a contradiction.

Comment: The other way around. I want to be able to set the templateUrl which means I have to get the information before the compile happens. In some of the module-types I may want to change the controller aswell. The more I talk about this I start to realize that Im trying to achieve too much in just one directive. Is it possible though ?

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems that the order of operations you're looking for isn't available, and this use-case for the `templateUrl` function is not supported or encouraged. While I personally don't agree with some of the reasoning, [you can read about it here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2895#issuecomment-58605529) and decide for yourself what you think.

Comment: I have tried looking at using template instead of templateUrl but I still need to change the controller in some cases which  puts me in a similar situation. Time to rethink how I want this to work. Thank you for your answer!  =)